# Background color not showing for a DIV

Tags: css

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but having trouble applying background color for #content. But it works fine if I set the height value to let say 800px. but I want it to be either auto or 100% as this template will be used throughout the site. any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="content_bg">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="contentLeft">   
        </div>
        <div id="contentRight"> 
            <div id="ContentPane" runat="server" />           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer_bg">
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="footerLeft">            
        </div>
        <div id="footerRight">           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

/*
====================================================================
Content Area
====================================================================
*/

.content_bg
{
    background:#dadad9 url(images/interior_content_bg_top.jpg) repeat-x center top;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#content
{
    width:980px;
    margin:auto; 
    height:auto; 
    background:#fff; 

}

#contentLeft
{
    float:left;
    width:209px; 
    margin-top:50px;   
}


#contentRight
{
    float:right;
    width:770px; 
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
}

/*
====================================================================
Footer
====================================================================
*/

.footer_bg
{
    background:#dadad9 url(images/interior_footer_bg.jpg) repeat-x center top;
    clear:both;
}

#footer 
{
    width:980px;
    height:258px;
    margin:auto;
    background:#dadad9 url(images/interior_footer.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}
#footerLeft
{
    width:400px;
    height:50px;       
    float:left;
    padding: 20px 0 0 25px;    
}

#footerRight
{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;       
    float:right;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: mind adding the html as well?

Comment: you have no content. height:auto; and height:100%; will still be 0px tall because you have nothing inside of them. the reason it works when you set a px height is because it forces a specific height. its not that the bg color isnt showing, its that your div is 0px tall.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set the overflow to auto for #content.

```
#content {
    width:980px;
    margin:auto; 
    height:auto; 
    background:#fff; 
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: @johnny - Because the content collapses when the children are floated and adding the overflow rule restores the behavior you'd expect.

Comment: Anyone struggling with a div showing background color in chrome, firefox and other browsers but failing to show div background color in Internet Explorer, this solution here will solve your problem. Thanks a bunch for this answer!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `#content` has no content. Since you are using `height:100%` for the div's height, it will expand to the full height of its parent div (i.e. `.content_bg`). However, `.content_bg` has no content either; therefore it is expanding to 100% of zero.

Comment: actually I do. I just modified the HTML code. sorry. It's generated from server since it's a CMS website.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the class to your id `<div id="content" class="content_bg">` and erase the class. And give your class these propertis

```
.content_bg
{
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then the content in your id "content" will define the width and height.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a problem applying background to `#content` because you didn't clear the floats. Add

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

After

```
    <div id="contentLeft">   
    </div>
    <div id="contentRight"> 
        <div id="ContentPane" runat="server" />           
    </div>
```